# Java Stream API -- How to reduce a loop to reduce

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have the following statement:

```
Function<Stream<Supplier<Collection<? extends User>>>, Stream<User>> userStreamSupplier =
   supStream -> {
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
    supStream.forEach(sup -> list.addAll(sup.get()));
    return list.stream();
};
```

Is it possible to convert a loop in the inner lambda to a smart stream.reduce operation (or other aggregation)? I'd tried various approaches but I failed.

Greetings,
JG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) instead:

```
supStream -> supStream.flatMap(supp -> supp.get().stream());
```

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.